# How to force desktop browser to use media queries designed for mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, media-queries

I've seen a bunch of stack overflow questions answered that address the problem of showing a desktop version on mobile, but I'm trying to discover how you could force a browser to render a mobile version of a site on desktop.

But is there some equivalent for desktop versions, so that I can 'trick' the browser into using media queries for a smaller device width? Essentially loading the mobile css onto the desktop version.

In essence I'm trying to add a toggle button that when clicked renders my page as though it were mobile. I'm aware you can achieve this affect with chrome tools, but I want to build in that functionality, and am struggling to figure out how to tell the browser to behave as though the viewport were mobile-sized.

Thank you!

Comment: You’re totally wrong on how media queries work. Those rules don’t address the device but the width of the viewport so actually if you resize the window, the style will change accordingly with those rules. If you want to do it in js you should just resize the window programmatically. But that’s pointless because you started from a wrong assumption. In chrome developer tools you have even the opportunity to see the page using specific devices (picking the corresponding window size) to test for design responsiveness

Comment: Or maybe you should just process the css rules when page has loaded and change the media queries so that the rules intended for smaller screen will apply despite the bigger resolution. But your question is really confusing when states: But on desktop, changing the viewport doesn't do anything to change which CSS rules are applied. FALSE. So or you just change the window size on desktop or you just load a js removing the rules bound to higher  size threshold. If that’s the case you intended, someone will tell you how

Comment: Thanks @DiegoDeVita --unfortunately there's not any relevant code as I'm figuring out how to even approach this. I'm aware that media queries are informed by the viewport. What I'm trying to get at is that if you want the browser to render a certain way on mobile, you can set a meta tag (named viewport) that specifies the content width (like how mahdiarrr74 did below). However this tag is ignored when rendered on a desktop. I want to mimic the functionality of the chrome dev tool by telling the browser to render the page as though the viewport were the width of a mobile device.

Comment: @trey you should have that in the developer tools on your browser ... ctrl-shift-i in the desktop browser and and the 2nd icon top left or press ctrl-shift-m ... it should switch to a mobile view

Comment: Best practice, (easiest and simplest), is to design for mobile first and then add for desktop. But, most people don't do it that way ... we are creatures of habit, and those who started by desktop first continue to do desktop first.

Answer (score 0):

if your CSS media queries doesn't work fine on desktop,
you're probably missing

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
```

and if they work fine but you want your website to has same view in both mobile and desktop, then why are you using media queries at all?

remove them and your CSS will work on every size as the same

Comment: Thank you but to add more clarity, my css looks as it should. I'm building chrome tools-like functionality and part of that is I want to be able to 'trigger' the browser to render my page as though it were a mobile page.

Comment: hmm, have you tried using an iFrame as a container for your page? you can change it's size in the simplest way using either CSS or JS And resizing it could result to page resize for the inner page

Answer (score 0):

load the site on your mobile phone, take note of the url. If it has a "/m", for example, "https://www.example.com/m" then include it as such in your desktop browser and the mobile version would be loaded. It works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).